# Split PDF into b&w and color parts (not pages)

Tags: pdf

I have to print a large multipage PDF where som pages contain color. To reduce the cost I'd like to print the black-only parts and I've found a lot of solutions to automaticall split the PDF into pure b&w pages and pages that contain color. Now, I have a little fear that if I print a page containing color that the black parts on the page will look different than the black from a b&w printer.

So, I was thinking if it is possible to split a page in a PDF into its black and colored components and print them on two different printers onto the same page. Here's an image to illustrate this:

[image]